# Inbox not updating if a comment is updated

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, edits, global-inbox

A comment was posted and a notification was pushed through to my Inbox as usual.

After looking at the comment I realized that the Inbox is not updating to correlate with what was edited by the user.

**Should the Inbox update if a comment is updated?**

[image]

Comment: That's right. The notification is for the _original_ comment. Edits don't get notifications.

Comment: @Oded Thank you for the clarification.