# Why would this answer show up in my inbox in Spanish, despite appearing in English?

Tags: support, global-inbox, languages

Please look at the screen shot. Why is the English answer shown in Spanish in my inbox?

I’m an English speaker in the USA (although I know a fair bit of Spanish). The person who provided the helpful answer in question has a Hispanic-looking name, so I am wondering in his language preferences made their way through to me in some unlikely and bugged code path?

Really fun bug, IMHO!

[Here is a link to the answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332679/can-a-mac-use-airplay-to-stream-to-stereo-homepods/406113#406113).

[image: Screen shot showing Spanish preview in inbox and English content answer in the main UI]

Comment: Most likely the answerer realized the answer should be in English so they edited it within the 5-minutes grace period but after the notification had already been pushed to your inbox.

Comment: We don't have language settings for the sites, though. Only SO sites are in non-English languages and each of them are specifically configured for that language - but we don't have a Spanish version of AskDifferent. :)

Comment: status-bydesign, similar Bug: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192439/282094

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the author of that answer wrote the post in Spanish, then realized it should be in English after seeing the other answers to that question.  You got the real-time notification in Spanish, but if the answer was translated to English in the [five-minute grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/798831), it wouldn't count as an edit, and wouldn't show in the timeline thus making you think it's a bug.

Comment: GP details are down at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Please tell me you wrote this answer in Spanish first and edited it within the grace period :)

Comment: @Glorfindel German actually, I don't know very much Spanish ;)

Comment: Das funktioniert auch.