# Orphan notification of answer on followed question - not in timeline - expected behaviour?

Tags: discussion, support, notifications, deleted-answers

I received a notification from a [question on Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/52134/is-the-decline-in-polio-symptoms-directly-caused-by-the-banning-of-pesticides-su) from a few months, clicking on that notification takes me to the question.

The answer from the notification is absent, I figure it's been deleted in a review process or by the author and I don't have the rep to see it.

The timeline for the question shows no such activity, none at all in the last month in fact:

[image]

One of my [deleted answers on another site](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/210725/timeline) shows-up in the question timeline - so there's some difference between the two cases.

Is this expected behaviour for a certain type of answer (spam/abusive say) or one deleted within a particular time-frame of a notification being received (ie. should I blame caching)?

Comment: It's a real-time notification, given at the moment of an answer. See a [related report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357582/1017231).

Comment: @bobble I suppose the question becomes "why doesn't it show in the timeline?"

Comment: Because you don't have the rep to see it outside of the timeline, so you don't have the rep to see it within. Once you get 10k you can see deleted answers in the timeline

Comment: I see. I also foresee accusations of timelines "gaslighting" people. Personally I'm fine with that though. @bobble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple. Just because you haven't earned earn the privelege of seeing deleted answer outside in answers column similarly you can't see the answers in timeline too. Earn 10k rep to see that deleted answer.

[image]